# Body element overflowing from the Big Wrapper in HTML5

Tags: html, css

I am having issues with my body element and my body wrapper. My website that I'm currently building is going to be responsive and everytime when I resize the browser's window width, the body element seems to be stretching the page together.

To understand what I'm trying to arrive to, please visit the link below.

**Link**: http://jsbin.com/uMuToHi/1/edit?html,css,output

There are 3 windows (HTML, CSS and output). Go to the Output window and use the Horizontal scrollbar and scroll to the right of the page and there will be a red background displayed. That red background is my body element.

I need to fix that problem before I can continue to optimise my website to be responsive. In the end, there shouldn't be any Horizontal scrollbar in the browser.

Thanks

Comment: Post your code here please.

Comment: There are a ton of problems with those media queries..

Comment: My code is rather long, hence i posted a link. That link leads to JSBin, an online debugging tool to edit webpages.

Comment: No offense, but that is a serious mess -- looks like it has grown by just slapping chunks together. I'd recommend you start that layout fresh, and add items and responsiveness via your media queries one piece at a time. Mobile first!

Comment: @RobM Yeah I might do that. Would you advise not to use Box Flex to make the website flexible. Although that can be done via media queries right ?

Comment: @Jeiman I wouldn't use flexible boxes (flexbox), as browser support isn't good enough. If you are looking to make it easier to do your responsive layout, it would probably be best for you to use ZURB Foundation or Bootstrap for your the grid framework.